# Setting up Kibana on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat

I have a lot of log files from JBoss Fuse that I want to visualize in Kibana.

I've installed Elasticsearch and Kibana.

I have also installed the plugin ingest-geoip (`bin/elasticsearch-plugin install ingest-geoip`).

Now I am trying to install Filebeat.

I've done this OK:

```
curl -L -O https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/filebeat/filebeat-6.2.2-darwin-x86_64.tar.gz
tar xzvf filebeat-6.2.2-darwin-x86_64.tar.gz
cd filebeat-6.2.2-darwin-x86_64/
```

But when I want to run it I get the following:

```
sindre@selite:/usr/lib/filebeat$ ./filebeat modules enable system
bash: ./filebeat: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

NB! This is my first time using Kibana. Please point me in the right direction if I am using it wrong. As I wrote earlier I want to use it for Jboss Fuse Log files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
filebeat-6.2.2-darwin-x86_64
```

There's your clue.  `darwin` is the name given to the core OS-X unix distribution

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_(operating_system)

It is extremely unlikely that a compiled darwin binary would be compatible with a linux system.

You really want to be looking at the [Linx X86 64 package](https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/filebeat/filebeat-6.2.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz)

Answer (score 0):

If you have running instance of Kibana on your system, you can easily configure it for any underlying operating system(Linux/macOS) with a few provided commands:

**visit:** `Home>>Add data>>System logs`

**current_url_for_demo:** `http://localhost:5601/app/kibana#/home/tutorial/systemLogs?_g=()`

**Visual Explanation:**
[image]